# CSS media screen breakpoint

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap 4, but in the bootstrap framework have already media queries breakpoints, now where should I use CSS breakpoints selector class? I have used a selector class in the div class row side but it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```css
@media(max-width: 992px){
    .section-4 .section-breakpoint{
      flex-wrap: wrap!important;
      justify-content: center!important;
    }
    .section-4 .section-breakpoint > * {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
   <section class="section-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row section-breakpoint">
                <article class="col-md-5 article first-article">
                    <hr class="hr-1">
                    <h2><i>More tools to help<br>
                        you do more</i></h2>
                    <h4><i>Analytics, social, and productivity</i></h4>
                    <hr class="hr-2">
                    <p>Easy-to-understand analytics ensure you're able to see at a glance exactly how well your website is performing with all Gator Website Builder accounts. Simple social media tools allow you to add live feeds from Instagram, Twitter, and Facebook in order to stay engaged. You can add G Suite productivity tools to your domain, enabling Gmail, Docs, Slides, and more.</p>
                    <h5><i><b>Get the best tools for $3.84/mo*</b></i></h5>
                    <a class="btn get-started-btn" href="#">BUY NOW</a>
                </article>
                <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
                    <img class="image-one" src="assets/images/product-7.png" alt="IMAGE-7">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened because bootstrap use `max-width`:

```css
@media(max-width: 992px){
    .section-4 .section-breakpoint{
      flex-wrap: wrap!important;
      justify-content: center!important;
    }
    .section-4 .section-breakpoint > * {
      width: 100% !important;
      max-width: 100% !important; /* Add this*/
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <section class="section-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row section-breakpoint">
                <article class="col-md-5 article first-article">
                    <hr class="hr-1">
                    <h2><i>More tools to help<br>
                        you do more</i></h2>
                    <h4><i>Analytics, social, and productivity</i></h4>
                    <hr class="hr-2">
                    <p>Easy-to-understand analytics ensure you're able to see at a glance exactly how well your website is performing with all Gator Website Builder accounts. Simple social media tools allow you to add live feeds from Instagram, Twitter, and Facebook in order to stay engaged. You can add G Suite productivity tools to your domain, enabling Gmail, Docs, Slides, and more.</p>
                    <h5><i><b>Get the best tools for $3.84/mo*</b></i></h5>
                    <a class="btn get-started-btn" href="#">BUY NOW</a>
                </article>
                <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
                    <img class="image-one" src="https://radiosol.cl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/default-img-400x240.gif" alt="IMAGE-7">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

You can try to use bootstrap class to get the same result without overrinding css.

Comment: No, actually I want to show col-md-5 width 100% in full container and next, col-md-7 width 100% in full container that's why I want to customize the bootstrap breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <section class="section-4">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row section-breakpoint">
                <article class="col-md-12 col-lg-5 article first-article">
                    <hr class="hr-1">
                    <h2><i>More tools to help<br>
                        you do more</i></h2>
                    <h4><i>Analytics, social, and productivity</i></h4>
                    <hr class="hr-2">
                    <p>Easy-to-understand analytics ensure you're able to see at a glance exactly how well your website is performing with all Gator Website Builder accounts. Simple social media tools allow you to add live feeds from Instagram, Twitter, and Facebook in order to stay engaged. You can add G Suite productivity tools to your domain, enabling Gmail, Docs, Slides, and more.</p>
                    <h5><i><b>Get the best tools for $3.84/mo*</b></i></h5>
                    <a class="btn get-started-btn" href="#">BUY NOW</a>
                </article>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-7 text-center">
                    <img class="image-one" src="https://radiosol.cl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/default-img-400x240.gif" alt="IMAGE-7">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```